# How to connect xyz points to a triangular polygon

Tags: java, polygon, triangulation

We have developed an xyz grid of floatpoints and we want to connect 3 points that are next to eachother to a triangular polygon. The Problem is that we get the wrong points to connect to a 3D mesh. How do you find the right ones?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an easy problem to solve, but it has been heavily studied. I recommend you look at Delaunay meshes:

---

[image: DelMeshBook]

---

Search also for "surface reconstruction from point clouds."